# Does the Pressure Vacuum Breaker (PVB) supply water to the sprinkler system of the house or the entire house?

Tags: plumbing, water, sprinkler-system

[image]

This Pressure Vacuum Breaker is between the city meter and the house. Usually when the layout is this way. If I shut these two valves off, does it stop the supply of water to the sprinkler system or the entire house?

Comment: it should only be for the irrigation system.  you should have a backflow preventer inside your house.

Comment: why ask here? ... just turn off the valves and see if your house still gets water

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally I would expect it to be for the sprinkler system but you never know. There is a valve on it, turn it off and then try the faucets etc in your home. If they quit it is a main cutoff, if they keep working it is for the sprinklers which at this point with the valve off they will not work.